# A private and offensive chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat, moderators

Here's a private room on the SE chat system. Look carefully at the URL.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21276/the-room-for-puzzling-mods-irritating-and-obnoxious-alarm-system

"Irritating and obnoxious". That's what our moderators call the community they're meant to be looking after, when they think we aren't looking. According to the [canonical blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), moderators are supposed to

> guide the community with gentle — but firm — intervention; respect [their] fellow community members at all times; demonstrate fairness and impartiality in [their] actions."

The name of this chatroom does **NOT** look like respecting their fellow community members.

---

Firstly (and this is why I'm posting here on meta), this is **something I feel the community should be made aware of**. Secondly, it's just possible the CMs don't know about it and will want to take action when they find out. I would think such a clear violation of the stated purpose of SE moderators calls for *some* kind of action, although I doubt it's serious enough to merit revoking anyone's diamond.

Please let me know if I'm going about addressing this issue in the wrong way!

*Thanks to @Doorknob for letting me know about this.*

Comment: Just so you know, I'm starting to get sick of investigating false accusations against the moderators. Maybe you should find a more productive use of your time...

Comment: @JonEricson I know I've made a fool of myself here, but it was a genuine mistake (as was my previous mistake re ad-hominem downvoting). You make it sound as though I'm cooking up false accusations just for the sake of accusing the moderators of something. I'm really not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> The Room© for Puzzling Mods'™ Irritating©® and Obnoxious© Alarm®™ System™

1. This name is obviously a joke.
2. It's the alarm system that's irritating and obnoxious, and even *that* is a joke.

This room has a bot that automatically posts things we might want to take a look at. We decided to have some fun with the name. That's all you're seeing, really.

Comment: OK, looks like I made a bit of a faux pas there! It was a genuine mistake though: I thought the name meant you had an alarm system for catching "irritating and obnoxious" posts. I've had the feeling in the past that certain users are being targeted for a lot of negative attention. I just parsed the name wrongly, and now I feel very silly. Sorry! :-)

Answer (score 20):

Here's the full name of the room:

> The Room© for Puzzling Mods'™ Irritating©® and Obnoxious© Alarm®™ System™

The way I read it, the adjectives refer to the alarm system not to any particular person. The only real activity in that room is a [chat bot](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/5072/smokedetector). I gotta say, that bot can be both irritating and obnoxious.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I parsed the name wrongly, thinking it meant they had an alarm system for catching "irritating and obnoxious" posts, which would have fit with the feeling I've had that certain users are being targeted for a lot of negative attention. OK, OK, I'm an idiot. Sorry.